# How can I make a foreign key relationship between an identity server column and another custom table?

Tags: asp.net-core, foreign-keys, identityserver4

I use identity server.

I know that if I want to add new columns, I make a new class which will inherit from `IdentityUser`, and in SQL Server with EF, the column will be generated. But I want to have a "Gender" column which will have a foreign key relationship with another custom-made table: "1" will be for "male", "2" for "female" etc.

I also want to make a similar relationship with another table where the programming languages of every employee will be stored.

Is that possible?

```
public ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public string FullName {get ; set; }
    public int GenderId { get ; set ;}
    public ICollection<ProgrammingLanguages> PL {get ; set ;}
}
```

Comment: Information about `gender` would actually be perfect to store as claim. Since that is part of the oidc user profile configuration, check the IdentityClaims table. So you shouldn't  extend the model for that. And you could do the same for `FullName`.

Comment: @RuardvanElburg: That's actually incorrect. Data can be a claim on the principal whether it's literally stored as a claim or on an extended user. (You can customize the claims that are added by default). However, something is should only be added specifically as a claim, when it is transient or not applicable to every user (such as a third-party auth token). In the case of something like gender, that should be stored on the user entity.

Comment: @ChrisPratt Do you have a source on that? Please note that I've written my comment in the light of `IdentityServer4`, where `gender` is already part of the oidc user profile. Extending the model with gender would be redundant, as you can simply add the claim in order to add it to the token. It also means that you'll need to add complexity in order to maintain the consent logic.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you need to implement one-to-many relationship between `User` and `Gender` tables and many-to-many relationship between `User` and `ProgrammingLanguage`. Many-to-many relationship requires extra table which will contain foreign keys to `User` and `ProgrammingLanguage` tables. You then need to override `OnModelCreating()` method and don't forget to call the base implementation of `OnModelCreating()` method so that let the base implementation to setup relationships between identity tables. You can read more on how to implement relationships between entities [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships). Here is the sample code how this can be done:

```cs
public ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public int GenderId { get; set; }
    public Gender Gender { get; set; }
    public ICollection<UserProgrammingLanguage> UserProgrammingLanguages { get; set;}
}

public class ProgrammingLanguage
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class UserProgrammingLanguage
{
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public ApplicationUser User { get; set; }

    public int ProgrammingLanguageId { get; set; }
    public ProgrammingLanguage ProgrammingLanguage { get; set; }
}

public class Gender
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class ApplicationContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Gender> Genders { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ProgrammingLanguage> ProgrammingLanguages { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.Entity<UserProgrammingLanguage>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasKey(pl => { pl.UserId, pl.ProgrammingLanguageId });

            entity.HasOne(pl => pl.User)
                .WithMany(u => u.UserProgrammingLanguages)
                .HasForeignKey(pl => pl.UserId);

            entity.HasOne(pl => pl.ProgrammingLanguage)
                .WithMany()
                .HasForeignKey(pl => pl.ProgrammingLanguageId);
        }

        builder.Entity<ApplicationUser>(entity => 
        {
            entity.HasOne(u => u.Gender)
                .WithMany()
                .HasForeignKey(u => u.GenderId)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
        })

        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Alexey for you reply,Now to the values of ProgrammingLanguage and UserProgrammingLanguage  for example,can i acces through the Db Set of ProgrammingLanguages ? And why i dont need DbSet<UserProgrammingLanguage> here in this solution?

Comment: You can add `UserProgrammingLanguages` collection (just like in `ApplicationUser` entity) to `ProgrammingLanguage` entity if you need to create a query for retrieving the list of users for a specific programming language. You can skip creating `DbSet` for the `UserProgrammingLanguages` if you don't plan to request this table directly via context.

Comment: EF Core doesn't technically support many-to-many relationships. You can fake an M2M via a join entity (`UserProgrammingLanguage` here). However, you don't have an M2M between `User` and `ProgrammingLanguage`; you have a one to many between `User` and `UserProgrammingLanguage` and a one to many between `ProgrammingLanguage` and `UserProgrammingLanguage`. That is why the collection must be typed as `UserProgrammingLanguage`.